# Can't bind to 'chartData' since it isn't a known property of 'div' in angular 2 with GoogleChart

Tags: angular

I do google chart with tutorial https://github.com/vimalavinisha/angular2-google-chart

Here is my component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleChart } from 'angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-ad-statistic-drink',
  templateUrl: './ad-statistic-drink.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ad-statistic-drink.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class AdStatisticDrinkComponent {
    public pie_ChartData = [
              ['Task', 'Hours per Day'],
              ['Work',     11],
              ['Eat',      2],
              ['Commute',  2],
              ['Watch TV', 2],
              ['Sleep',    7] ];
    public pie_ChartOptions  = {
      title: 'My Daily Activities',
      width: 900,
      height: 500
    };
}
```

And here is my html page

```
<h2>  Pie Chart</h2>
<div id="pie_chart" [chartData]="pie_ChartData" [chartOptions] = "pie_ChartOptions" chartType="PieChart" GoogleChart></div>
```

This is my app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule, Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule, Http, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { GoogleChart } from 'angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MenuComponent } from './menu/menu.component';

import { AppRoutingModule }     from './app-routing.module';
import { provideAuth, AuthHttp, AuthConfig }      from 'angular2-jwt';

import { MenuService } from './menu/menu.services';
import { MenuDirective } from './menu/menu.directive';

export function authHttpServiceFactory(http: Http, options: RequestOptions) {
  return new AuthHttp( new AuthConfig({}), http, options);
}

@Directive({
  selector: 'input'
})

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MenuComponent,
    MenuDirective,
    GoogleChart
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: AuthHttp,
      useFactory: authHttpServiceFactory,
      deps: [ Http, RequestOptions ]
    },
    MenuService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

When i run project, it generates errors about it:

```
Can't bind to 'chartData' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("<h2>  Pie Chart</h2>
<div id="pie_chart" [ERROR ->][chartData]="pie_ChartData" [chartOptions] = "pie_ChartOptions" chartType="PieChart" GoogleChart></di"):
```

Comment: importing  **GoogleChart** in your app.module is in the right path?

Comment: yep, it is right, i install **angular2-google-chart** into node-module, then add it into app.module with right path.

Comment: Have the same error in Angular4. Did you solve this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import {GoogleChart} from '../directives/angular2-google-chart.directive';

@NgModule({
  imports: [ ],
  declarations: [GoogleChart]
})
```

Also,

Use *ngIf to ensure that variable **pie_ChartData** has already been initialized in the component as below.This prevents application from breaking if **pie_ChartData** is not initialized.

```
<div *ngIf="pie_ChartData" id="pie_chart" [chartData]="pie_ChartData" [chartOptions] = "pie_ChartOptions" chartType="PieChart" GoogleChart></div>
```

Comment: it still announces that error. Component cannot understand **[chartData]** and **[chartOptions]**

Answer (score 0):

Please add code below to module:

```
import { GoogleChart } from 'angular2-google-chart/directives/angular2-google-chart.directive';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        GoogleChart,
    ]
})
```